# how to Checked if value of static checkboxes are equal on what you have in your database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I have this column in my database named "source_income"
[image]

Which was Imploded from my EDIT page.
[image]

Problem is after I save the record, I see all the checkboxes are checked. I understand that the cause of the problem is that I do not have something that will check if the value of the checkbox should be equal to what I have in the database.

The checkboxes on my form are not dynamic.

```xml
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('source_income') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
        <strong>Check all that apply to you:</strong>
        <br>
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'employed', null, ['id' => 'employed']) !!}            
        {!! Form::label('employed', 'Employed') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'online-seller', null, ['id' => 'online-seller']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('online-seller', 'Online Seller') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'rider', null, ['id' => 'rider']) !!}            
        {!! Form::label('rider', 'Rider (Grab,Lazada,Etc.)') !!}                        
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'small-business-owner', null, ['id' => 'small-business-owner']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('small-business-owner', 'Small Business Owner') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'no-income', null, ['id' => 'no-income']) !!}            
        {!! Form::label('no-income', 'No income') !!}
        <br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'remittances-allotment', null, ['id' => 'remittances-allotment']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('remittances-allotment', 'Remittances / Allotment') !!}
        {!! $errors->first('source_income', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT,BLADE.PHP

```php
public function edit($id, Profile $model)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
    $profileSourceIncome = explode(",", $profile->source_income); 

    return view('dashboard.profile.edit', compact('model','profile'))
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('profileSourceIncome', $profileSourceIncome);
}
```

I literally stopped in this part `$profileSourceIncome = explode(",", $profile->source_income);`

My question is how can I able to display the checkboxes checked if the name of the checkbox is equal to any value from `$profileSourceIncome[]`?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html), you only need to pass `true` as the third parameter in your `Form::checkbox(...)` calls to return a checkbox that is already checked.

```php
public function edit($id, Profile $model)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
    // Turn this array into a Collection
    $profileSourceIncome = collect(explode(',', $profile->source_income)); 

    return view('dashboard.profile.edit', compact('model','profile'))
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('profileSourceIncome', $profileSourceIncome);
}
```

And then, in your blade file, you could use the [Collection's `contains()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains) to do the following:

```xml
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'employed',              $profileSourceIncome->contains('employed'),              ['id' => 'employed'])
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'online-seller',         $profileSourceIncome->contains('online-seller'),         ['id' => 'online-seller']) 
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'rider',                 $profileSourceIncome->contains('rider'),                 ['id' => 'rider'])
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'small-business-owner',  $profileSourceIncome->contains('small-business-owner'),  ['id' => 'business-owner'])
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'no-income',             $profileSourceIncome->contains('no-income'),             ['id' => 'no-income'])
Form::checkbox('source_income[]', 'remittances-allotment', $profileSourceIncome->contains('remittances-allotment'), ['id' => 'remittances-allotment'])
```